# RegEx to capture what's between opening and closing square brackets

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to build a regular expression that captures anything between square brackets like the following numbers.

`[phone]010101[/phone]   [phone]434343[/phone]
[phone]3443434[/phone]`

so the matches should be 010101, 434343, 3443434

I built `cow([\s\S]*?)milk` to experiment, and this seems to capture multiple matches and works fine with multiple lines, achieving what I exactly need.

However when I attempted to build the actual regex using this: `\[phone\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/phone\]` , it would only capture the first single match.

What could be wrong with my expression?

Comment: What are you trying to capture? For example in `[phone]010101[/phone]` what is your expected output? `010101` or `phone` & `/phone`?

Comment: There's a problem with your input string.  Can you see it?  (one of the brackets is turned the wrong way).

Comment: If you fix the problem with your input string, your regex works.  https://regex101.com/r/z7eJMD/1

Comment: Robert, this seems to be a python version, does this also work on the JavaScript version for you? and yes I fixed the typo.

Comment: Sorry I was missing the global & multi-line flags. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. This will capture the numbers as you intend.

```
\](.*)\[
```

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/f77Ejz/1)

Answer (score 0):

The regex is correct but global and multi-line flags are missing. In JavaScript, with `g` (global) and `m` (multiline) flags added to regex, intended matches can be found.

```js
str=`[phone]010101[/phone] [phone]434343[/phone]
[phone]3443434[/phone]`;
reg = /\[phone\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/phone\]/gm;
[...str.matchAll(reg)].map(x=> x[1]); //["010101", "434343", "3443434"]
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question: *What could be wrong with my expression?*